# How do I determine non-rectangular drawing regions in Gtk+ 3 with cairo?

Tags: c, gtk, cairo, gtk3, inkscape

The [Gtk+ 3 migration guide](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/checklist-gdkeventexpose-region.html) shows how the `GdkEventExpose.region` field can be used to provide a fine-grained area for re-rendering widgets.  We already do something like this in Inkscape to avoid rendering excessive amounts of complicated stuff on our drawing canvas.

However, the example in the guide shows how to do this for the old Gtk+ 2 expose_event handler.

How do I do the equivalent in a new Gtk+ 3 draw handler, which receives a "ready-clipped" Cairo context as a parameter, rather than a `GdkEventExpose`?

I guess one possibility is to use `cairo_copy_clip_rectangle_list` on the "ready-clipped" cairo context to obtain a list of rectangles that make up the region to draw.  Does anyone have any experience of using this?  Does it seem like a sensible approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use cairo_copy_clip_rectangle_list() on the cairo_t that you get in your widget's ::draw() signal handler.  See this commit for an example:
http://git.gnome.org/browse/vte/commit/?id=21a064ac8b5925108b0ab9bd6516664c8cd3e268

Comment: Thanks... only just spotted this answer!  I eventually implemented it using the method you pointed to :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I have not much clue, I decided to check the source code. GDK emits a `GDK_EXPOSE` event on a window and creates the `GdkEventExpose` instance for this.

This event is then handled in gtk/gtkmain.c via `gtk_widget_send_expose()`:

http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkwidget.c?id=eecb9607a5c0ee38eadb446545beccd0922cb0b8#n6104

This function clips the `cairo_t` to `GdkEventExpose.region`, as you already learned in the docs.

This then calls `_gtk_widget_draw_internal()` which emits the actual draw signal:

http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkwidget.c?id=eecb9607a5c0ee38eadb446545beccd0922cb0b8#n5726

As far as I can see, nothing here let's you access the clip region directly. In `gtk_widget_send_expose()` the `GdkEvent` is added as userdata to the cairo context. However, this is not accessible, because all the involved functions and variables are static. So you'll have to use `cairo_copy_clip_rectangle_list()`.

However, this sounds quite inefficent. First `gdk_cairo_region` transforms the region into a number of calls to `cairo_rectangle` and then cairo transforms this from its internal representation into a `cairo_rectangle_list_t` (which may fail if the clip is, for some reason, not a region). If you see this being slow, it might make sense to have some shortcut for this added to gtk directly.